# User Instance uses Path for database name when attached in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2005, database-connection

When I attached my database to SQL Server Express, my database name got changed to my database address. Can someone help me to figure this out?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats how it works - whats the issue?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the database name to be a database address path !!! Because it makes it  problem for me to backup

Comment: Thats not how a "User Instance" is intended to be used. Create a normal database if you want to name it and back it up.

Comment: please tell me more

Comment: If you are unsure about the normal process of creating and accessing a SQL Server database I recommend finding a tutorial as its a big topic.